# pointer on pointer array of arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

i searched for my problem, but didn't found it.

I have a declaration of an pointer array

```
int *Blocks[] = {Block1,Block2,Block3,Block4};
```

The Blocks are arrays with a length of 50.

Now i have a for-loop, there i want to step by step init the fields

```
for(int i=0;i<50;++i)
{
*(Blocks[section])+i = 1;
}
```

The One should be a variable later.
Is it right or whats the right expression to get the array field of the selected section?

Thanks to every answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that line isn't quite right. The following is (note the position of the parentheses):

```
*(Blocks[section]+i) = 1;
```

or, equivalently but more concisely:

```
Blocks[section][i] = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote almost works, you can do:

```
*(Blocks[section] + i) = 1;
```

But the best solution would be to use C's syntactic sugar and write:

```
Blocks[section][i] = 1;
```

Comment: thank you both! Blocks[section][i] = 1; is what i've searched for

Answer (score -1):

you may set init that fields as

```
*(Blocks[section]+i) = 1;
```

and maybe you should malloc enough memory before you init Blocks